# How do you turn of the touchpad when typing to avoid the cursor jumping around?

Tags: touchpad, cursor

It is nearly impossible to type on my Dell Latitude because the cursor jumps around anytime I get close to the touch pad.  There is not a setting to inactivate it during typing.  I am using Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: System Settings > Mouse and Touchpad does not have any options to disable while typing.

Answer (score 1):

I use the Touchpad-Indicator; I have it set as a startup application in Ubuntu, and it's set to turn off the touchpad.

I'm using Unity, and first had to turn on the notification area (you don't have to leave it showing there after you've set it up, but it's a convenient tool to have for turning the touchpad back on):

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['all']"
```

This allows the indicator to show in the panel.

Then install the indicator:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install touchpad-indicator
```

It works great for me with my Dell Studio.

Answer (score 0):

This should be asked in [superuser](https://superuser.com/). It's typically a *fn key* for that in every laptop. In my case is *fn f9* but yours could be other one. Just look for the key with symbol that symbolize the touchpad, maybe in blue collor or orange or any other color different that the characters colors.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem on 2 different laptops on Lubuntu. Neither has a fn key for toggling the touchpad on+off.  I found this script, which I would like to attribute properly to the author or source, but I've unfortunately since lost the reference to the source. It is not my creation. 
Copy this code + save to a file with the extension `.sh` :

```
#!/bin/bash

read TPdevice <<< $( xinput | sed -nre '/TouchPad/s/.*id=([0-9]*).*/\1/p' )
state=$( xinput list-props "$TPdevice" | grep "Device Enabled" | grep -o "[01]$" )

if [ "$state" -eq '1' ];then
    xinput --disable "$TPdevice"
else
    xinput --enable "$TPdevice"
fi
```

I have it saved as `touchpad-toggle.sh` on the desktop.
Change permissions to make it executable: right-click the file, Properties, Permissions tab, change the Execute box to "Owner" or "Anyone."
Clicking on the file toggles the touchpad on or off.

Also, in the file manager preferences (in my case, PCManFM):
I have selected "Don't ask options on launch executable file" (check in the box).